# How to animate a fade between two menu items

Tags: android, animation, menu, menuitem

I have toolbar with a view pager and two tabs which are fragments in my application. When the user swipes between the two, a different menu item displays in the toolbar. I am able to do this with no problem. However, I want to get a fade animation between the two menu items when they are switching.

How I achieve the switch between the menu items follows.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    this.menu = menu; //get reference to menu

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I get a reference to the menu onCreateOptionsMenu() method.
Then using an update method I pass a value when the tabs are switched.

```
private void updateMenuTitles(int value)
{
    if(value == 0)
    {
        MenuItem sort = menu.findItem(R.id.sort_menu);
        sort.setVisible(true);

        MenuItem dateRange = menu.findItem(R.id.date_range);
        dateRange.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(value == 1)
    {
        MenuItem dateRange = menu.findItem(R.id.date_range);
        dateRange.setVisible(true);

        MenuItem sort = menu.findItem(R.id.sort_menu);
        sort.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

XML for the menu.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/date_range"
    android:title="@string/sort_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_date_range_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/sort_menu"
    android:title="@string/sort_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sortName"
            android:title="@string/sort_name"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sortSize"
            android:title="@string/sort_size"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sortDate"
            android:title="@string/sort_date"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sortLastUsed"
            android:title="@string/sort_usage"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            />
    </menu>

</item>
```

The above works fine. The problem arises when I want to add an animation between
sort menu item and the dateRange menu item, when switching tabs.

I have search and tried to use the following stackoverflow posts with no
success.

[Changing view on Menu Item in Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935875/changing-view-on-menu-item-in-action-bar)

[getActionView() of my MenuItem return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286768/getactionview-of-my-menuitem-return-null)

[Animated Icon for ActionItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731602/animated-icon-for-actionitem)

[Add ActionBar Items with a fade animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434704/add-actionbar-items-with-a-fade-animation)

Using the above information I tried setting an android:actionViewClass which
returns null when I try to fetch it. Then I tried app:actionViewClass which makes my menu item disappear.

I tried to setActionView in the code instead of  XML, then try to animate
that with no luck.

I also tried to use android(app):actionLayout. Make an ImageView layout, but that makes my menu item unclickable and I was still unable to animate the fade.